# When still to use InfoPath?

Tags: infopath

I am looking for a way to modify SharePoint list forms so that I can make some fields read-only, and can apply some logic based on the person logged into the form. I have been told that InfoPath should no longer be used and we should be looking for alternatives. Could anyone provide me with a non-code solution which would allow me to make fields read-only and allows me to have buttons which are only available when a specific person is logged into a form?

Regards,

Lucas

Answer (score 3):

InfoPath will be supported till 2023 as Microsoft says. Also they are looking forward for a more responsive design supported tool. Which may come with SharePoint 2016. So feel free to use it. They will not easily drop it all the way given there are many services that use .xsn file format such as Biztalk.

Answer (score 2):

InfoPath may be discontinued by Microsoft but in the official statement, they make it very clear that they will keep supporting InfoPath for many years to come. So it's up to you to decide whether to use it or not.

> How long will InfoPath be supported?
>
> - The InfoPath 2013 client will be supported through April 2023.
> - InfoPath Forms Services for SharePoint Server 2013 will be supported    until April 2023.
> - InfoPath Forms Services in Office 365 will be    supported until further notice.

See the whole post to get all the answers. - [Update on InfoPath and SharePoint Forms](http://blogs.office.com/2014/01/31/update-on-infopath-and-sharepoint-forms/)